# how to select the value from "Span Type dropdown" in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how to select the value from "Span Type dropdown"  in Selenium webdriver

I am able to click on dropdown by using XPath but not able to select the value from the dropdown.
My XPath for clicking on Dropdown is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='minexpButton']/span")).click();
```

When i use the above code in Selenium, dropdown is expanded but i am not able to select the value from the Dropdown

MY HTML code is as below:

```
<span id="minexpButton" class="yui-button yui-menu-button yui-button-active yui-menu-button-active" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: -moz-inline-box;">

<div id="minexpSelectionMenu" class="yui-module yui-overlay yui-button-menu yui-menu-button-menu" style="z-index: 1003; visibility: visible; left: 367.683px; top: 1050.6px;">

<div class="bd">
<div class="selectionMenu">
<div class="ulDiv" style="overflow: auto; width: 64px; height: 210px;">
<div class="liDiv selected">

<a class="txt_black heading_4" href="#" tabindex="-1" target="_self">- Min -</a>
</div>

<div class="liDiv">
<a class="txt_black heading_4" href="#" tabindex="-1" target="_self">0</a>
</div>

<div class="liDiv">
<a class="txt_black heading_4" href="#" tabindex="-1" target="_self">1</a>
</div>
```

How can I select the value from dropdown?

Comment: please add the code for selecting the value from the drop-down and .//*[@id='minexpButton']/span --> I dont see a span tag which is the child of tag with id = 'minexpButton'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to select values from your drop-down
The below function will select 0 value from the drop-down, you can parameterize the following line 
(temp.equals("0") and pass the value which you want to select

```
 List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".txt_black.heading_4"));
    for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++) {
        String temp = element.get(i).getText();
        if (temp.equals("0")) {
            element.get(i).click();             
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the application you are automating is using YUI Library.

Note in YUI Library clicking on every element with class containing 'yui-menu-button' will display the menu items of the dropdown. These menu items are wrapped in a DIV element containing class 'yui-menu-button-menu'.

The architecture of the application in your case is implementing a suffix. I believe and correct me if I'm wrong, the ID of all dropdowns on the page are in the format:

**[dropdownName]Button**  & **[dropdownName]SelectionMenu**

eg.

```
<span id="countryButton" class="...">
</span>
....
<div id="countrySelectionMenu" class="">
....
</div>
```

So the actual name/id of the dropdown is 'country'. In the above case it is 'minexp'. (Minimum Experience I think. Therefore DropdownID is 'minexp' and not 'minexpButton' or 'minexpSelectionMenu'. It may apply similarly to other elements in your application. Please conduct an architectural review of the application to get a better understanding of the element IDs and YUI library.

Here is how you can select from a YUI SelectMenu (dropdown):

```
// Remember dropdownID is the 'minexp' and not 'minexpButton' or 'minexpSelectionMenu'    
public void selectOption(String dropdownID, String optionText) {
       // Get the dropdown button
       WebElement dropdownButton = driver.findElement(By.id(dropdownID & "Button"));

       // Click on the dropdown button, this will make the selection menu visible
       dropdownButton.click();

       // Get the dropdown selection menu, since it is now visible you can select from it
       WebElement dropdownMenu = driver.findElement(By.id(dropdownID & "SelectionMenu"));

       // Verify selection menu is visible
       if(dropdownMenu.isDisplayed()) {
             List<WebElement> menuItems = dropdownMenu.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
             for(WebElement menuItem : menuItems) {
                if(menuItem.getText().trim().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(optionText.trim().toLowerCase())) {
                       menuItem.click();
                       break;
                }
            }  
       }        
}
```

Tried and tested on the [YUI Library for Dropdown](http://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0/examples/button/btn_example07.html).

I hope this helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(“dropdownField”)).sendKeys(“mention text of required 
 value from dropdown”); //send required option in dropdown field
driver.findElement(By.id(“option1”)).click();
```

Or try with the below code:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath(“”));
for(WebElement option : options) {
if (option.getText().contains(“mention text of required value from dropdown”)) 
{
 option.click();
 break;
}
```

Please refer to the [link](https://biswasarpita.medium.com/selecting-dropdown-option-with-selenium-19ef06e1d5fa) for more details- how to select a particular value in a dropdown without using the methods of Select class in Selenium.